# 'Undefined is not a function' in momentjs function DIFF

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have the following code:

```
var dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';

var time_margin = 10;

var last_message = moment().format(dateFormat);

var comparison = moment(last_message).add(time_margin, 'seconds').format(dateFormat);
var actualtime = moment().format(dateFormat);
var secondsDiff = actualtime.diff(comparison, 'seconds');
console.log("secondsdiff",secondsDiff);
```

It crashes right in `var secondsDiff = actualtime.diff(comparison, 'seconds');` with `Missing error handler on "socket".
TypeError: undefined is not a function.`

`comparison 2015-04-12 18:00:41
actualtime 2015-04-12 18:00:42`

What might be wrong? I'm really not understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call `diff` on a string. When you call `moment().format(dateFormat)`, what you have as result is a string, not an instance of `moment`.

In order to fix it, you need to call `diff` without formatting:

```
var dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
var time_margin = 10;
var last_message = moment().format(dateFormat);

var comparison = moment(last_message).add(time_margin, 'seconds').format(dateFormat);
var secondsDiff = moment().diff(comparison, 'seconds');
console.log("secondsdiff",secondsDiff);
// => secondsdiff -9
```